# Why does this PIXI.js code use a lot of memory?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

The following code crashes Chrome (79.0.3945.130) after using around 1500Mb of memory and I'm not quite sure why.

Is there a more efficient way to just draw simple shapes repeatedly?

```js
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

const app = new PIXI.Application({ width, height });

const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
app.stage.addChild(graphics);
graphics.beginFill(16763904);

app.loader.load(setup);

function setup() {
  document.body.appendChild(app.view); 
  app.ticker.add(d => render(d));
}

function render() {
 const x = randomInt(0, width);
 const y = randomInt(0, height);
 graphics.drawRect(x, y, 3, 3);
}

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.2.1/pixi.js"></script>
```

Comment: pixi is a retained scene graph. It remembers everything you ask it to draw so as you call `graphics.drawRect` you're adding more and more rectangles to it's pile of data. This is so you can later move all the rectangles, draw them before or after something else, and do all kinds of operations on them. If you just want a bucket of pixels with without keeping track of the rectangles itself you should consider just using [plain canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)

Comment: @gman Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense and it was what I was observing when doing a memory profile. I've now switched to using canvas via p5.js